# jQuery validation works but not the right way

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a simple jQuery validation where I need to check required fields over different pages in my website.

At the moment I have a the following code which works. I check the function *check_inputs()*, but in my opinion this is not the right way.

```js
// Check the required fields
function check_inputs() {
    var errors = false;
    jQuery('#wiz-action .required').each(function () {
        var input = jQuery(this);
        if (input.val().length < 1) {
            input.addClass('error');
            errors = true;
        } else {
            input.removeClass('error');
            errors = false;
        }
    });

    if (errors == false) {
        return true;
    }
}

// Check fields on blur
$('#wiz-action input.required').blur(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    input.removeClass('error');
    if (input.val().length < 1) {
        input.addClass('error');
    } else if (!input.val().match(/^\d+$/)) {
        input.addClass('error');
    }
});


// Check fields by clicking "next" link 
$('#next-link').click(function (e) {

    if (check_inputs() == true) {
        // Do something

    } else {
        $('.error-message').fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
    }
});
```

```css
.error {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wiz-action">
    <input type="text" class="required">
    <input type="text" class="required"> 
    <a id="next-link" href="#">Next</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? I will get a better idea by what you mean

Comment: @VRC Here is a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5z8r166v/1/

Comment: @VRC My problem is that I am not very familiar with jQuery. So I can make simple functions, but do not know if I've made the right way.

Comment: Can you please also include in your question the expected way that this script should run and what it should validate?

Comment: You can use [jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for keeping/managing the validations simple and clear. however your code do need few optimizations.

Comment: if the last element is without error it will validate. you must not set errors to false within each function. remove the line `errors = false;` (which comes after `input.removeClass('error');` )from it because it overwrites previous errors

Comment: @Spokey I needs to work like it does now, but as I said to VRC, I don't know if I do it a clean and right way.

Comment: @Kyborek You mean in the if statement in the _check_inputs()_ function?

Comment: @Kyborek I have removed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a jsfiddle and have changed a few things.
http://jsfiddle.net/5z8r166v/3/

I have created a focus for when you click on the element. Here I remove the error class. 
This is just a frontend decision but I made it remove the red line.

And when clicking out (blur) I check if there is a value and then set the error class if there is no value in it. 
 
I use the == "" to check if its empty instead of length. Here you have to calculate the length of the string. 
 
It is just bit better for performance. 
I know you won't notice it tho cause its only milliseconds + I find it easier to read.

In the next click I have added

```
e.preventDefault();
```

which prevents the default action of the button. Not sure what you wanna do but know when to use it.

You have added regex. Probably this is needed for what character you allow.
You forgot to check it in the next button click. Added it there too.

There was actually an error in the next button click loop thing. You did do this

```
  if (input.val().length < 1) {
        input.addClass('error');
        errors = true;
    } else {
        input.removeClass('error');
        errors = false;
```

But if the last textbox is good and there is still a empty or invalid textbox, the variable is overriden with false which making it continue in the next button click which isn't correct.

Also make use of good variable names. 
I have used hasError instead of errors since it is a boolean type. 
Also you returned the variable there like this

```
if (errors == false) {
    return true;
}
```

but since it's a boolean you just have to return the value. 
If you want to reverse boolean before sending then use

```
return !hasError
```

but in this case it wasn't needed.

Last but not least : You choose OnLoad but OnDomready is enough since you don't work with images.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for you time! I appreciate it very much! The focus part is a nice frontend decision. And the length part is also an improvement. Also returning the hasError variable instead of checking first is the  best. You answer certainly helped me!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check the required fields
function check_inputs() {
    var errors = false;
    $('#wiz-action .required').each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val().length < 1) {
            input.addClass('error');
            errors = true;
        } else {
            input.removeClass('error');
            errors = false;
        }
    });

    if (errors == false) {
        return true;
    }
}

// Check fields on change
$('#wiz-action input.required').change(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    input.removeClass('error');
    if (input.val().length < 1) {
        input.addClass('error');
    } else if (!input.val().match(/^\d+$/)) {
        input.addClass('error');
    } else {
        input.removeClass('error');
    }
    check_inputs();
});


// Check fields by clicking "next" link 
$('#next-link').click(function (e) {

    if (check_inputs() == true) {
        // Do something

    } else {
        $('.error-message').fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
    }
});
```